# How to Adjust Weights Using PCA?

Tags: r, pca

I have a data set composed of 5 indicators `D1`, `D2`, `D3`, `D4` and `D5`, and their weighted sum `DS`, which I use to create the binary variable `EP`.

```
library(tidyverse)

weight <- rep(1/5,5)
names(weight) <- c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5")

data <- data.frame(D1 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   D2 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   D3 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   D4 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   D5 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

data <- data |> mutate(DS = rowSums(across(D1:D5,  ~ .x * weight[cur_column()])),
                       EP = if_else(DS >= 0.4, 1, 0))
```

I use equal weights to calculate `DS`, but I know the weights should not be equal since the variables are of different importance to `EP`.

I have seen this presentation [here](https://composite-indicators.jrc.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/COIN%202017%20Step%205%20Weighting%20methods%20%28I%29%20PCA_0.pdf) about calibrating the weights using PCA, and I would like to do the same for my data.

Can someone please show me how to use PCA in order to calibrate the weights according to the importance of the variables `D1:D5` to the variable `EP`? Thank you very much in advance.